# Accessing Angular app's props and controller functions from external non-Angular plugins

Tags: javascript, angularjs, external, medium-editor

I have an Angular SPA but in it I'm using some non-angular library (Medium Editor [ME from now on] to be exact). I created a directive for ME so if I add a `contenteditable` element on my views, ME get's instantiated and works properly. So that's not a problem.

The problem is that I also created a special ME extension that requires to make web requests to my server in order to insert correct markup into ME's editable element. But to make these requests it requires some view-model's data and also communicate it back:

- it needs to read and set (when undefined) my view model ID
- it needs to *constantly* manipulate some other view model value in order for my SPA to know that it's still processing so other processes get postponed

I thought I'd simply include `input type="hidden" ng-model="..."` on my page and change its value and trigger *input* event so Angular would update its model. Hidden input of course doesn't work. So I changed it to `input type="text" class="hidden"` and keep the functionality.

This does work, but it doesn't seem to be the proper way of doing things as it's hackish. And this mainly works for model value exchange (get/set). How about if I would have to call some controller function? Is that even remotely possible?

I don't want to make ME's extension to rely in any way on Angular library as it has to be purely ME extension and should be reused in non-Angular SPAs (maybe some other lib SPA or just pure simple DHTML web app). But I would like to make it usable in SPAs as well as ME can easily be used to manipulate some element's markup that can be set to view model through a directive.

**What it the proper way of communicating with Angular app from external libs that aren't native to Angular?**

### Additional info

Basically I want to have 4 functions in my custom extension that should somehow access (and manipulate) my Angular view model:

- `getReferenceId()` and `setReferenceId(id)`
- `incrementPending()` and `decrementPending()`

Pending counter could be exposed publicly and accessed by my Angular SPA, so it wouldn't process data while extension is still doing its own stuff. But SPA doesn't have any authority over when to set reference ID so it would correctly be read by the extension...

Answer (score 0):

This is usually solved by wrapping external plugins (or their parts) in ng services and directives. You don't need the input tag, just put the data on scope and after changing from non-ng code call `$scope.$digest`. If you need to watch for data change to trigger something in external library, you can use either `ng-change` or `$scope.$watch`.

Comment: This ME extension has no externalized members I could access from my SPA... Could you also show some example code to support your claims so I could easily point out points that aren't applicable in my case and why?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Then create these members, it is your extension, right? So it is your responsibility to make it play nicely with third-party, i.e. Angular. See js-data and js-data-angular for example.

Comment: But extension even with external assessors wouldn't help as it's not angular's responsibility to control its flow but it's rather extension's responsibility to inform other parties of its whereabouts. Your answer doesn't really help in this regard... And to call `$scope.$digest` (I'd rather use `$apply` though) I'd need to access my Angular's application from external script, which is something that can only be achieved more or less with hacks. Angular wasn't designed to be used in this way. I suppose `$scope.$watch` is as close as possible to solve my problem.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik You have to expose methods in your extension that can be either be called from controllers or fed with callbacks (or make use of $q promises). It is the only straightforward way to synchronize third-party code with digest cycles. It is hard to give a quality answer because you don't post any code.

Comment: I've added additional info. The problem with exposing my extension's functions/variables is not actually a viable solution because extension is not *slave* here, but rather master. So my extension should be manipulating view model and not the other way around... Well. Pending count could be requested from from the outside (SPA) but reference ID has to be requested and set from extension.

Comment: I think that your problem (Angular not being master) is quite uncommon. SPA is usually comprised Angular directives (components) which can wrap non-Angular extension(s) and services (in case of global extensions). I'm curious, what is the reason behind putting Angular under some other library/framework?

If your extension has only one instance per page, you could expose a service to `$window` and communicate through it. It's IMO not nice, but I'm not sure I ever saw using Angular this way. Even better question, is Angular supposed to be used this way?